# Dúvida sobre Redes Neurais

Tags: python, if, redes-neurais

eu tinha tinha terminado o curso de Redes Neurais com python, e simplesmente depois de ter treinado toda minha rede neural, me bateu uma dúvida na questão da utilização da mesma. Por exemplo, depois que a minha rede passa por todo o processo de Feed Forward, ela retorna na camada de saída (por exemplo 0.406)  com a função sigmoide já aplicada. O problema é que eu não sei como eu faria uma verificação para dizer se é 0 ou 1 ou algo assim, para o usuário poder entender a saída. Não sei se seria algo como:

```
if respostaCamadaOculta < 0.5:
    return 0
else:
    return 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para isso, estamos entrando em uma definição que é hora conceitual e hora situacional.

Do ponto de vista de conceito, o output 0.406 pode significar qualquer coisa, e a única coisa que ele define é o que o modelo entendeu, usando de base a arquitetura do modelo / funções de saída, o treinamento e os inputs do caso específico, inputs esses que foram calculados como uma consequência dos pesos encontrados ao analisar os padrões. Ou seja, conceitualmente o número não define, necessariamente, a sua interpretação (no seu caso, se deve considerar 0.5 como limite de separação / regra de corte para interpretá-lo como `0` ou `1`). Portanto sua resposta é situacional, e não conceitual.

Agora, entrando no ponto situacional, a primeira pergunta que você precisa se fazer é: Qual o output esperado do modelo?
Porque se você está usando um output único (que acredito seja o caso), então o que você obteve foi a probabilidade desse output ser o definido como estado `1`, ou seja, nessa aplicação seria de 40.6%.

**Agora, respondendo a sua dúvida,** você tem que se perguntar:
`Como vou tratar meu output`?

No geral, um modelo mais simples, seria tratar o binário de acordo com uma regra de corte como a que você mencionou (usando 0.5 como o separador do resultado).

Porém, não necessariamente isso é verdade para qualquer modelo. No caso de chatbots com `NLU`, é comum usarmos valores diferentes de 0.5 (se quiser dar uma olhada nisso, usar o `Google Assistant` com o `DialogFlow` é um bom caminho para entender o que estou dizendo).

Então, em resumo, você tem que saber a melhor forma de interpretar o valor final, de acordo com o resultado que espera do seu modelo, e o tipo de dados que está analisando!

***Se quiser comentar aqui na resposta um detalhamento melhor do seu modelo, para ajudar com ideias de como interpretar, para a sua aplicação, fique à vontade!***